# self reference in monkey patched python class

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to understand the *self* reference in a patched method. The code is the following:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = lambda: none
        self.child.string = "child's string value"
        self.string = "string value 1"
        print "initialized"
    def func1(self):
        print self.string

if __name__=="__main__":
    foo0=foo()
    foo0.newMethod = lambda: "test"
    print foo0.newMethod()

    foo0.func1()    
    foo0.child.secondMethod = foo0.func1
    foo0.child.secondMethod()
```

Why does the child's method refer its *self* to foo0? Is this any different from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that question lies in Python's distinction between unbound method and bound methods. When you define a method, it's *unbound*: it can operate on any instance of the class, and it is, in fact, nothing more than a function whose first argument is named self (and even then, it's a convention) and a little bit of checking so you don't do truly horrible things with them.

```
class Foo(object):
    def my_method(self, arg):
        print "self:", self
        print "arg:", arg

a = Foo()
print Foo.my_method(a, 2)
# self: self: <__main__.Foo object at 0x000000000219DE10>
# arg: 2

# You could, in theory, do that, but Python complains because it values the sanity
# of the people who will have to maintain your code :p
print Foo.my_method(1, 2)
# TypeError: unbound method my_method() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

So far, nothing special. However, Python has a bit of magic when we call a method not on the class itself (as is done above), but on *an instance* of that class (that is, on an object).

```
a.my_method(2)
# self: <__main__.Foo object at 0x000000000219DE10>
# arg: 2
```

Notice how suddenly you only have to supply `arg` to the method, even though it's defined with two arguments? That's because `a.my_method` is a *bound method*: it's the `my_method` method of the `a` *object*, not that of the `Foo` *class*. It is bound to that particular instance, and has a reference to that particular object in it (if you look at `dir(a.my_method)`, you'll notice it has a `im_self` attribute).

However, in your example, if you were to add a `print self` statement in `func1`, it would print `foo0` instead of `foo0.child`. That's because the "binding" happens not when you *call* the method (`foo0.child.secondMethod()`), but simply when you reference it (`foo0.func1`).

More importantly, it only ever happens when you reference a method that you defined on a class.

So in your example, `foo0.child.secondMethod = foo0.func1` references `foo0`'s `func1` method (which gives you a bound method of `foo0`), but no magic is performed in the assignment itself. It's simply setting an attribute of `foo0.child`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: this used to catch me out a lot.  If your asking, "why bound methods?" as far as I can tell it solely for those times when you might pass an object's method as an argument, or store it in a variable to be called later.  Then a bound method will remember who its object (self) is.

Comment: this is the opposite of javascript, a situation which I find very interesting.